# when run testcases with mvn test from CMD, testNG testcases not run but junit run

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-surefire-plugin

CMD: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAIxm.png)

POM.xml file:
contains all dependencies required for the project. But when i go to run the project with mvn test, it did not testcases handled by testNG and run only testcases handled with junit. This is because of some issue by testNG but did not get it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumE2E</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>SeleniumE2E</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <listeners><listener class-name="Framework.SeleniumE2E.Listners"></listener></listeners>
    <test name="Google">
        <classes>
            <class name="Framework.SeleniumE2E.Google" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TesValidateUIt">
        <classes>
            <class name="Framework.SeleniumE2E.ValidateUI" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="AppTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="Framework.SeleniumE2E.AppTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

One test case:

```
package Framework.SeleniumE2E;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObject.LoginPagee;

public class Google extends base {
    public WebDriver driver; // Make public driver to stop initializeDriver() function to be overridden in case of parallel tests run
    @BeforeTest
    public void Initialize() throws IOException {
        driver = InitializeDriver();
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "getdata")
    public void googlePage(String Email, String Password) throws IOException {

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        LoginPagee lp = new LoginPagee(driver);
        lp.EmailID().sendKeys(Email);
        lp.password().sendKeys(Password);
        lp.submit().click();
    }
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getdata() {
//      Row: How many different data types test should run
//      Column: How many vaues each test
        Object[][] data = new Object[2][2];
//      0th row
        data[0][0] = "hamza.abbas4947@";
        data[0][1] = "Ham@5625";
//      1th row
        data[1][0] = "hamza.abbas4947@gmail.com";
        data[1][1] = "Hamza@5625";
        return data;
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void killbrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: First upgrade to most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin(3.0.0)... are your tests TestNG based or JUnit Jupiter based? Best would be to show an example of your test code...

Comment: Tests are TestNG base but i created only one sample test is that is junit based for the purpose of testing

Comment: update version of surefire but did not work

Comment: So do you want to run your TestNG based tests via JUnit Jupiter or all tests with JUnit Jupiter (I would recommend to do) or do you have only TestNG based test? If so remove junit jupiter dependency... otherwise you need to use junit-jupiter testng engine (more details https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-3)